# Sulu CMS not working after installation

Tags: nginx, content-management-system, sulu

Trying to install and configure Sulu CMS.

I am using Homestead and have configured the vhosts to welcome a new site and have run `vagrant provision`:

```
sites:
- map: sulu.cms
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/sulu_cms/public
```

I have pulled sulu-standard from the GIT repo, checkedout, ran `composer install` and followed [the instructions given here](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/getting-started/setup.html) to the dot. I am also using the Nginx configuration [shown here](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/getting-started/vhost.html) and the default **Webspace** provided by the installation.

However, when trying to access the host after I am getting a **502 Bad Gateway** error. Could anyone enlighten me on the issue?

I am running Homestead on Windows 10, I have a couple of other Laravel-based projects running in the same Homestead box without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've also created an issue for that [on Github](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-standard/issues/672) and posted the answer there. You've mentioned there that the vagrant mapping was incorrect, because it showed to a non-existent `public` directory instead of the `web` directory.

So the correct vagrant mapping would look like this:

```
sites:
- map: sulu.cms
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/sulu_cms/web
```

Would be nice if you could also mark this as the accepted answer, or create a more detailed one on your own.